# Is there a mechanism to know whether the user is actually using Mathematica or has just left it running idle?

Tags: licensing

The monitorLM below shows the user logged in as `sagar` has been running the Mathematica for 13days. I don't understand whether Mathematica is actually in use by this user or else whether he launched Mathematica and then left it idling, but this is wasting of one of my licenses.

Could you please tell me how to resolve this issue.

```
Licenses in Use: 
Program              Version Class   Username      Hostname            Duration
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Mathematica          11.1    B       smrutimahapat smrutis-macbook-pro  2:04:31 
Mathematica          11.2    B       sagar         cauchy               13d  2h
```